# AWS elastic beanstlk cron job

Tags: python, flask, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying `flask` in python using `AWS elastic beanstalk`.

I wrote the code using `threading.timer()` because I want to crawl every certain time, but it works in the local environment, but not when deployed to `AWS`.

First of all, what is the reason??

Secondly, I know that I need to create a `.config` file in the `.ebextension` file to make a cron job on elastic beanstalk.

https://aws.amazon.com/en/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/

I saw the link above, but since it is an example via `.sh` file, I really don't know how to apply it.

Therefore, we would appreciate your help in how to do cron to crawl.

Below is the status of the file paths.

> -.ebextensions
> >- cron-linux.config
>
> -static
>
> -templates
>
> -application.py
>
> -requirements.txt
>
> -Enterprise.txt
>
> -crowler.py

Comment: You do it exactly as in the link you've provided. In the `myscript.sh` you would invoke your python script.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I don't know what to do

Comment: The example is in the link you've provided. I don't have a python script that you use for crawling. But I can assure you the example in the link works. I used it on my own EB. So you need to adapt it your specific use-case and the python script.

Comment: For example, what about the code that allows you to save the current time in a .txt file every 5 minutes?

The .txt file is in the same path as application.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be as in the example from the link. You just change cron schedule to 5 minutes, and the path were to save the `date`. You can try the following:

In your app you could have a python file called `crowler.py`:

```
import time 
now = time.strftime('%H%M%S') 
f=open('Enterprise.txt','w',encoding='UTF-8') 
f.write(str(now)) 
f.close()
```

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            */5 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

    "/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            python3 /var/app/current/crowler.py

            exit 0

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for doing that. But I want to save the .txt file with python code as below.


`import time
now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')
f=open('Enterprise.txt','w',encoding='UTF-8')
f.write(str(now))
f.close()`

Comment: Thank you very much. Let's add it based on this code.

Comment: After modifying the cron-linux.config file and crowler.py as above, compressing it with .zip, and deploying it to elastic beanstalk, the .txt file is not updated after 5 minutes, but retains the original contents. I modified the file path above, but what is the problem? I have tested loading a .txt file on a webpage to see if it gets updated.

Comment: @김준우 Hi. Sorry, there should be `python3`, not `python`. Also the `Enterprise.txt` will be created in `/root` folder as cron runs as root. Remember that your app runs as `webapp` user, so it will not have access to any files created by `root`. You have to adjust all the permissions and paths to your requirements.

Comment: I understood what you mean. But how do you set the path and set permissions? As for Linux, it is a beginner level that only knows simple commands.